# ##[error]The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-deploymentgroups

I have created a deployment group for deploying a Windows Service into Azure VM which is in a domain.
Also, I successfully ran the script on the VM to create the agent (I checked PAT checkbox).

When the Release task tries to download the artifacts, it throws an error:

```
**2022-04-06T21:50:26.3881776Z ##[error]The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.**
2022-04-06T21:50:26.3889924Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.logissue type=error;]The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.
2022-04-06T21:50:26.3897699Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.complete result=Failed;]
2022-04-06T21:50:26.4225965Z ##[debug] at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.VssHttpRetryMessageHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncBuffered(Task1 sendTask, HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts)    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage message, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, Object userState, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.SendAsync[T](HttpRequestMessage message, Object userState, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Location.Client.LocationHttpClient.GetConnectionDataAsync(ConnectOptions connectOptions, Int64 lastChangeId, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Object userState)    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.Location.VssServerDataProvider.GetConnectionDataAsync(ConnectOptions connectOptions, Int32 lastChangeId, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.Location.VssServerDataProvider.ConnectAsync(ConnectOptions connectOptions, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.Location.VssServerDataProvider.EnsureConnectedAsync(ConnectOptions optionsNeeded, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.Location.VssServerDataProvider.CheckForServerUpdatesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.Location.VssServerDataProvider.FindServiceDefinitionsAsync(String serviceType, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.Location.VssServerDataProvider.GetResourceLocationsAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssConnection.GetClientInstanceAsync(Type managedType, Guid serviceIdentifier, CancellationToken cancellationToken, VssHttpRequestSettings settings, DelegatingHandler[] handlers)    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssConnection.GetClientServiceImplAsync(Type requestedType, Guid serviceIdentifier, Func4 getInstanceAsync, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssConnection.GetClientAsync[T](CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.TaskExtensions.SyncResult[T](Task`1 task)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssConnection.GetClientT
at Agent.Plugins.BuildServer…ctor(VssConnection connection)
at Agent.Plugins.PipelineArtifactServer.DownloadAsync(AgentTaskPluginExecutionContext context, ArtifactDownloadParameters downloadParameters, DownloadOptions downloadOptions, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Agent.Plugins.PipelineArtifact.DownloadPipelineArtifactTaskV1.ProcessCommandInternalAsync(AgentTaskPluginExecutionContext context, CancellationToken token)
at Agent.PluginHost.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

When I logged into the VM, I noticed that the artifact download folder was created but empty.

Please advise how to resolve this issue.